# complexity of set of nameduple lookup

Tags: python, dictionary, set, namedtuple

Hi in Python i have a namedtuple because i want to store a few values in the same object.

```
A = namedtuple("A", "key1 key2 key3")
```

I store those A's in a registry class which holds a set()

```
class ARegistry(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._register = set()


    def register(self, value1, value2, value3):
        self._register.add(A(key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3)

    def __getitem__(self, value1):
        return next((x for x in self._registry if x.key1 == value1), None)

    def get_by_key2(self, value):
        return next((x for x in self._registry if x.key2 == value), None) 


    def get_by_key3(self, value):
        return next((x for x in self._registry if x.key3 == value), None)
```

In this way i can easily retrieve those namedtuples by key1 which i need in most cases (80%), but also on key2 or key3 (other 20%):

```
 myobj1 = a_register["foo"]  # Search on key1
 myobj2 = a_register.get_by_key2("bar")  # Search on key2
 myobj3 = a_register.get_by_key3("bar")  # Search on key3
```

**Question:**

Now from that i read in the documentation about sets, is that lookup in sets is of complexity O(1). But is this still true if i store namedtuple in sets like in the example above? Or does such a construct increase the lookup time of objects in my registry and is another method of being able to lookup values by multiple keys preferred, time-wise.

Comment: You're not utilizing the `O(1)` lookup of sets at all. Everything you have here is `O(n)` since you are iterating across the set instead of doing a membership check. If you want `O(1)` you should use a dictionary where you have 3 entries for each instance, one for each key, where the value is the instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookup in a set is only O(1) if you are looking for the item in the set.  You are looking at each item in the set to see if it matches a particular criterion -- which is completely different (It'll be O(N) complexity on average).

A more efficient way to store this would be to put the tuple into a dict that maps the key to the tuple.  You'll need 3 dicts to store the data this way (so there is more memory involved in this approach if that is a concern)

```
from collections import defaultdict

class ARegistry(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._register = [
            defaultdict(list),  # lookup based on first item in A
            defaultdict(list),  # lookup based on second item in A
            defaultdict(list),  # lookup based on third item in A
        ]

    def register(self, value1, value2, value3):
        tup = A(key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3)
        for v, registry in zip(tup, self._register):
            registry[v].append(tup)

    def __getitem__(self, value1):
        return next(iter(self._register[0][value1]), None)

    def get_by_key2(self, value):
        return next(iter(self._register[1][value]), None)

    def get_by_key3(self, value):
        return next(iter(self._register[2][value]), None)
```